# $\lim _{x\to 2}\:\frac{x}{x^2-4}$ Why using L'hopital rule is wrong?

Tags: limits

$$\lim _{x\to 2}\:\frac{x}{x^2-4}$$

It diverges, by differentiating you get 1/4, but the answer isn't 1/4

In what conditions i can't use L'hopital rule?

Thanks...

Comment: It's not a limit of the indeterminate form $0/0$.

Comment: It's only applicable in cases of indeterminates. $2/0$ is not indeterminate, since that diverges no matter what. $0/0$ _is_, however, because sometimes it doesn't diverge (such as $x/x$ when $x$ goes to $0$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use L'Hospital because you don't have an indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\pm\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. Notice that if $x \to 2⁺$, then $x^2 - 4 > 0$, and this way $\lim _{x\to 2^+}\:\frac{x}{x^2-4} = +\infty$. On the other hand, $x \to 2^-$ means that $x < 2$, then $x^2 - 4 < 0$, and so $\lim _{x\to 2^-}\:\frac{x}{x^2-4} = -\infty$. Since $$\lim _{x\to 2^+}\:\frac{x}{x^2-4} \neq \lim _{x\to 2^-}\:\frac{x}{x^2-4},$$ the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

The given fraction is not of any indeterminate form since the numerator is equal to $2$ as $x \to 2$, so the use of L' Hopital's rule is not justified.

Answer (score 2):

L'Hopital's rule only applies if when you evaluate the numerator of the expression at the limit, $2$ in this case, you get that they are either both zero, or both infinite. Since when you evaluate the numerator at $2$ you get $2$, you cannot use L'Hopital's rule.